# Stuck in writing python program

Tags: python

I am stuck in writing the python code for below problem, can anyone help to find the issue with the code is much appreciated.

Selection of kits.

Bob and Alice start painting. There are N numbers of painting kits. The įth kit has a strength of Ai.

They need to select these kits. Bob got the first chance to select a kit and he selected a minimum number of kits such that he can make the painting quickly. Now, the remaining kits are selected by Alice.

Bob can finish his painting before Alice, if and only if the total strength of his kits is greater than Alice's,

Find the minimum number of kits that must be selected by Bob.

Input format
• The first line contains N. • The second line contains N space-separated
integers denoting the strength of kits.

Output format
Print the minimum number of kits that Bob must select.

Expected output- 2

```
def Kit_sol(N,arr):
    arr.sort(reverse=True)
    Bob = 0
    Total_sum = 0
    for i in arr:
        alice = sum(arr)-i
        if Bob > alice:
            Total_sum += 1
        else:
            Bob += i
            return Total_sum
    
N = 5
#int(input())
arr = [5,3,4,1,2]
#list(map(int,input().split()))

out_ = Kit_sol(N, arr)
print(out_)
```

[Code written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OFI1.jpg)'''

Comment: Please add your code (properly formatted) in the question rather than giving a link to an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```py
def Kit_sol(N,arr):
    arr.sort(reverse=True)
    Bob = 0
    Alice = sum(arr)
    for i, v in enumerate(arr, start=1):
        Bob += v
        Alice -= v
        if Bob > Alice:
            return i
```